# Removing trailing and leading spaces of a field using AWK or SED

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a database text-file (csv-like) that contains excessive trailing and leading spaces. These incidents only occur around character "|", which is used to separate columns. My goal is to remove these spaces using awk or sed. I can't get this seemingly simple task to work; is it perhaps because | is a special character?

**Input.txt**

```
| |COL1 |COL2  |COL3      |COL4 |COL11|COL99|COL19     |COL88     |CAL9            |COL84           |COL98           | 
| |500  |0001  |0100000000|1995 |001  |     |Test  This|00.00.0000|           6,14 |          12,00 |           0,00 | 
| |500  |0001  |0100000000|1995 |002  |     |Separ ated|00.00.0000|          18,14 |          12,00 |           0,00 |
```

**Output.txt**

```
||COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4|COL11|COL99|COL19|COL88|COL9|COL84|COL98|
||500|0001|0100000000|1995|001||Test  This|00.00.0000|6,14|12,00|0,00|
||500|0001|0100000000|1995|001||Separ ated|00.00.0000|18,14|12,00|0,00|
```

Comment: You ask for sed or awk, but tr should be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
sed 's/ *| */|/g' file
||COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4|COL11|COL99|COL19|COL88|CAL9|COL84|COL98|
||500|0001|0100000000|1995|001||Test  This|00.00.0000|6,14|12,00|0,00|
||500|0001|0100000000|1995|002||Separ ated|00.00.0000|18,14|12,00|0,00|
```

It change any `<space>|<space>` with `|` so other space are not removed.

Comment: While this does cover the case the OP proposed, it is worth noting that this will not remove leading whitespace in the first column if not proceeded by a separator.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all spaces with `awk` by forcing `awk` to recalculate the output using the new value of `OFS` to separate the fields (which were split on whitespace to begin with).

```
awk -v OFS='' '{$1=$1; print}' in.csv
```

To remove just "field separating" spaces try this:

```
awk -F '[[:space:]]*\\|[[:space:]]*' -v OFS='|' '{$1=$1; print}' in.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

use `sed` like:

```
   sed 's/ *\(|\) */\1/g' file
```

use `awk` like

```
awk '{gsub(/ *\| */, "|");print}' file
```

edit:
use `gawk` like

```
gawk '{print gensub(/ *(\|) */, "\\1","g")}' file
```