# Unix - Remove Leading/Trailing Spaces (Column Wise)

Tags: unix, awk, sed, tr

**I have text lines like these below:**

```
P,   123456  ,01,A,H, 123456 ,123456 123456 ,,
P,123456   ,01,A,H, 123456,   123456 123456,,
P,  123456,01,A,H,123456 ,123456 123456 ,,
P, 123456,01,A,H,   123456,  123456 123456,,
P,123456 ,01,A,H,123456   ,123456 123456  ,,
```

**I want them to be like below:**

```
P,123456,01,A,H,123456,123456 123456,,
P,123456,01,A,H,123456,123456 123456,,
P,123456,01,A,H,123456,123456 123456,,
P,123456,01,A,H,123456,123456 123456,,
P,123456,01,A,H,123456,123456 123456,,
```

**Requirements:**

1. Remove all leading & trailing spaces from 2,6,7 column only
2. Values in 7th Column should remain separated by single space only

**Research:**

I have tried many combinations with `awk`, `sed`, `tr` but could not succeed according to my requirements. I would like to have a preferable solution in `awk`, `sed`, `tr` only because all my clients have limited CYGWIN installed. So I cannot ask all my clients to install new executable.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting and add the commands you tried instead of just saying that you tried...

Comment: I also tried this solution, but its not working
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28548655/3676305

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk -F' *, *' '$1=$1' OFS=, file
```

Understandable way:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" *, *"; OFS=","} $1=$1' file
```

As commented by @glennjackman, safer to use

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" *, *"; OFS=","} {$1=$1; print}' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `FS`  - Set input field separator
- `OFS` - Set output field separator
- `$1=$1` - This will make `awk` to format the fields with `OFS`. This returns `true` which makes `awk` to print current line (reformatted).

Comment: worked flawlessly !!!
Thanks a lot. It would be nice if you can describe your solution a bit, that would be more helpful in further developments.

Comment: @user3676305, Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Your solution has been marked as "Accepted"

Comment: Pedantically, `$1=$1` returns true *if* $1 is a non-empty string or is not the number 0. That happens to be the case for this input, but if not, you'll be missing rows in the output. Test with input `echo -e '0,first\n1,second\n,third'`. Safer to use `{$1=$1; print}`

Comment: Another small problem, because you're only removing spaces around the field separator with this solution, it doesn't remove leading spaces in the first field or trailing spaces in the last field. A quick fix is to add `sub(/^ +/,""); sub(/ +$/,"");` at the beginning of the main block.

Answer (score 2):

sed is a good choice too.

```
sed 's/ *, */,/g' file
```

We're assuming this CSV file does not contain a line like this:

```
a, b, "this field, this very one, should not be touched", d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",$i); print $0}' file_path
```

or:

```
awk -F' *, *' '{for(i = 1; i < NF; i++) {printf $i","}; printf $NF"\n"}' file_path
```